# Error attempting to override HtmlGenericControl in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following class:

```
Public Class HtmlGenericSelfClosingTag
    Inherits HtmlGenericControl
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(tag As String)
        MyBase.New(tag)
    End Sub
    Public Shadows Property TagName As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.TagName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.TagName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Controls As ControlCollection
        Get
            Throw New Exception("HtmlGenericSelfClosingTag cannot have child controls.")
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Overrides Property InnerHtml As String
        Get
            Return String.Empty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Throw New Exception("InnerHtml cannot be set on an HtmlGenericSelfClosingTag")
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Overrides Property InnerText As String
        Get
            Return String.Empty
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Throw New Exception("InnerText cannot be set on an HtmlGenericSelfClosingTag")
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Overrides Sub RenderControl(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        MyBase.Render(writer)
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagLeftChar & Me.TagName)
        Attributes.Render(writer)
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have declared the control as:

```
Protected WithEvents MyElement As HtmlGenericSelfClosingTag
```

I have the html tag defined as:

```
<HtmlGenericSelfClosingTag ID="MyElement" runat="server" />
```

I am getting the following error during page render:

> The base class includes the field 'MyElement', but its type (MyClass.HtmlGenericSelfClosingTag) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl).

I have searched DuckDuckGo (and, by extension, Google, etc) to find out what else I need to override to make my class compatible with the HtmlGenericControl class, but no dice.  I have also checked the MSDN docs but no mention of override requirements.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the `<HtmlGenericSelfClosingTag ID="MyElement" runat="server" />` tag from the aspx file, and simply adding the control directly in code, as in:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.head.Controls.AddAt(0, BaseElement)
End Sub
```

And to avoid rendering the control twice, I modified the `Render` code:

```
Public Overrides Sub RenderControl(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagLeftChar & Me.TagName)
    Attributes.Render(writer)
    writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd)
End Sub
```